# re module has no attribute compile

Tags: python

I am trying to use the following command in Python 3:

```
text = re.compile('attribute')
```

but it tells me that that 're module has no attribute compile'. Has the command been updated in Python 3?

Comment: did you `import re`?

Comment: try running `dir(re)` from the command line, what is the output?

Comment: @Paul Rooney Yes I did import re.

Comment: @Mike McMahon File not found.

Comment: @Mike McMahon I was in the Python main directory.

Comment: from the python terminal, run `import re` then `dir(re)` this should tell you all of the attributes/method definitions associated with the imported module.

Comment: Do you have another `re.py` file in your directory?

Comment: @Mike McMahon yes compile is a method. now the question is why isn't it recognising this...

Comment: what is the output of `import re; import sys; print(sys.modules['re'])` ?

Comment: @johncip <module 're' from 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\re.py'>

Comment: I'm not on Windows but that looks like it's the correct module.

Comment: Do you have a `re` variable declared somewhere? Is your code dynamically importing any modules (which might shadow the built in `re` module)?

Comment: @Abu Ashraf Masnun I might do. Is there a quick way to solve such a conflict?

Comment: import `re` just where you used the `re.compile` - but remember it might override the other `re` variable.

Comment: @Abu Ashraf Masnun I am already doing this. It's still not working.

Comment: `del sys.modules['re']` then `import re`

Comment: @Abu Ashraf Masnun Still the same error message...

Comment: Can you please manually open up the `re.py` file in your Python directory and see what's in there?

Comment: @Abu Ashraf Masnun Yes. compile is in the re file.

Comment: Can you show the error message, please.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably because your filename is "re.py".

Answer (score 2):

Yes it was a case of some code I imported shadowing the the inbuilt re. I solved this by making sure I put the import of re at the very last of my imports so it took precedence.

Comment: I would say the better solution would be to not shadow the standard lib `re` at all

Comment: You could also use following construction: `import re as standardre` and then use `standardre.compile()` in code.

Answer (score 2):

You can debug such scenario by using `imp.find_module()`:

```
import imp
imp.find_module("re")
```

It will tell you which `re.py` is imported.

Answer (score 2):

if anyone gets here you might have just used a name for your .py that is already a library.  I made one called enum.py and got this error.  I renamed it to something unique and all was happy again.

Thank you for your feedback, I will add to my answer to make it more clear as to why is it relevant to the original question.

The original question had an issue after importing their own module called re I did the same but named my enum. Some of the answers here were helpful but vague. I am making it more clear that you must use unique names in your code or can experience this with any attribute, class or function that is used by the library or its dependencies. By me having this file enum.py in my project folder I pretty much broke my interrupter. The point of my reply is that if you find yourself here like did, this might help you quicker than reading all the other steps that were taking to get to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your pip version using: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` in the cmd

Then import regex module again using: `pip install regex`.