# Python: import calendar error gives unexpected result

Tags: python-3.x

Some other things are asked which is not in my code after execution

```
import calendar
y = int(input("Input the year : "))
m = int(input("Input the month : "))
print(calendar.month(y, m))
```

Filename I write it as calen.py

```
E:\pyprogs>python calen.py
Enter a string: df
fd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "calen.py", line 1, in <module>
    import calendar
  File "F:\Anaconda\lib\calendar.py", line 10, in <module>
    import locale as _locale
  File "F:\Anaconda\lib\locale.py", line 180, in <module>
    _percent_re = re.compile(r'%(?:\((?P<key>.*?)\))?'
AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'
```

I expected the calendar to be printed.

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34783230/3001761?

Comment: Do you get that error running that code alone?

Comment: This is not about your code but about the Text Editor or similar that you are using. Without a lot more information about the details of how you have set up your machine it is not possible to help you. Try using the IDLE editor that came with your Python installation to run the code to see it is not the code itself that is the problem.

Comment: The code works fine. Perhaps you named a variable `re` somewhere