# can not import etree from lxml

Tags: python, import, syntax-error, lxml

I run file with a single line: **from lxml import etree**.

In IDLE (python 3.8 32-bit) - its run OK. When running the file in console I got an error:

> from lxml import etree
>
> File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 74, in init lxml.etree
>
> File "src\lxml_elementpath.py", line 62, in init lxml._elementpath
>
> AttributeError: module 're' has no attribute 'compile'

What's wrong? I did not have any problem running with other packages. I wanted to switch from xml.etree to lxml

My OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit operating system

python: Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 22:39:24) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

lxml install output: Collecting lxml. Using cached lxml-4.5.0-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (3.3 MB). Installing collected packages: lxml. Successfully installed lxml-4.5.0

Comment: Seems like a problem with the regex package in python. These Link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783230/re-module-has-no-attribute-compile

Comment: Still on Windows 7? Do note: [End of support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-7-support) was in January 2020.

Comment: You may have two versions of Python and hence two versions of `lxml`. Compare at top of IDLE and console (after entering `python`).

Comment: From console, after running python, import lxml is accepted without error.

Comment: OK. It seems that I have some problem running this file from certain directory only. I copy the file to another directory, and there was no problem running it. the original directory name is D:\python.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. The issue is closed